# How to use grep on all files non-recursively in a directory?

Tags: grep

I want to search for a string of text in all files in a directory (and not its subdirectories; I know the `-r` option does that, but that is not what I want).

1. Running

   ```
   grep "string" /path/to/dir
   ```

   is supposed to be able to do this, I've read, but it gives me the error:

   grep: dir: Is a directory
2. Next, I tried running `grep` on multiple files.

   `grep "string" .bashrc .bash_aliases` works perfectly.

   `grep "string" .bash*` works as intended too.

   `grep "string" *` gives me the errors:

   ```
   grep: data: Is a directory
   grep: Desktop: Is a directory
   grep: Documents: Is a directory
   grep: Downloads: Is a directory
   ...
   ```

Only the errors are printed, I don't get the matching lines. I tried using the `-s` option, but to no avail.

So, my questions:

1. Why am I not being able to use `grep` on a directory, as in (1), when I should be able to? I've seen that done in plenty examples on the Internet.
   **Edit**: When I say "using grep on a directory", I mean "search in all the files in that directory excluding its subdirectories". I believe that this is what grep does when you pass a directory to it in place of a file. Am I incorrect?
2. Please give me an explanation on the workings of `grep` that would explain the behavior of commands in (2).
   **Edit**: Let me be more specific. Why does using wildcards to specify multiple files to search in for work with `.bash*` and not with `*` or even `./*`?
3. How can I search all the files in a directory (and not its subdirectories) using `grep`?

Comment: Also you're relying on the shell expanding wildcards such as `*`, known as globbing. Globbing does not include filenames starting with a dot such as `.bashrc` as standard. You can set shell options so that it will include these files, but you can get yourself in a bit of a mess if you don't know what you're doing. A good guide to understanding globing can be found here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: I dunno why, but I've always done globbing on hidden files, and it has always worked. I haven't change any setting or something. As I pointed out in (2), it works with `grep "string" .bash*` too.

Comment: Sorry, my last example was incorrect.  You can search in hidden files as well, and suppressing the "is a directory" because Linux technically sees directories as a different type of file.  The command would be then:  `grep "string" * .* 2>/dev/null` or `grep -s "string" * .*`

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/q/9217185/3701431

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Bash, a glob will not expand into hidden files, so if you want to search **all** the files in a directory, you need to specify hidden files `.*` and non-hidden `*`.

To avoid the "Is a directory" errors, you could use `-d skip`, but on my system I also get an error `grep: .gvfs: Permission denied`<sup>†</sup>, so I suggest using `-s`, which hides all error messages.

So the command you are looking for is:

```
grep -s "string" * .*
```

If you are searching files in another dir:

```
grep -s "string" /path/to/dir/{*,.*}
```

---

Another option is to use the `dotglob` shell option, which will make a glob include hidden files.

```
shopt -s dotglob
grep -s "string" *
```

For files in another dir:

```
grep -s "string" /path/to/dir/*
```

---

† Someone mentioned that I shouldn't get this error. They may be right - I did some reading but couldn't make heads or tails of it myself.

Comment: Is there any reason for the space between `*` and `.*`?

Comment: @Hashim Compare the output of `echo * .*` and `echo *.*` run in your home directory, and the difference should be obvious. Otherwise LMK and I'll explain it.

Comment: Interesting, so `echo *` shows non-hidden files and folders, `echo *.*` shows non-hidden files, `echo .*` shows all files, and `echo * .*` shows all files and directories. But why the reason for the space between the two in the latter case? It feels messy to me. Is there not a way to combine the two to get the same results? Or otherwise is there a syntax explanation of why the two need to be separated here, or is `* .*` an exceptional case?

Comment: @Hashim I'm not sure how you came to those conclusions, so let me explain. First, directories are files in this context. In globs, `*` represents all non-hidden files (i.e. filenames which **don't** start with a dot); `.*` represents all hidden files (i.e. filenames that **do** start with a dot); and `*.*` represents all non-hidden files which **contain** a dot. In `echo * .*`, the two globs must be separate because they are different globs: one for non-hidden, one for hidden. Though as I wrote in my answer, you can make `*` include hidden files by turning on the `dotglob` shell option.

Comment: Using `*.*` is common on Windows (DOS) as a way to list all files but on *nix will only include files with a dot in them, so it doesn't make sense on *nix.  Instead you use `*` to list all files except hidden files, and `.*` to list hidden files.

Answer (score 12):

You need the `-d skip` option added on.

1. Grep is searching inside of files.  You can search recursively, as you said, if you want to search files inside of a directory.
2. By default, grep will read all files, and it detects the directories.  Because by default you have not defined what to do with the directories with the `-d` option, it give error output.
3. Searching just within the parent directory would be `grep -d skip "string" ./*`

Comment: For more information on grep, see `man grep`.

Comment: (a) Please see the edit. (b) Using `-d skip` does not work; it's basically the same as `-s`; also, see the edit. (c) Nope, `grep -d skip "string" ./*` does not work either.

Answer (score 8):

Old timers would probably do this:

```bash
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "string"
```

Comment: Why not `find . -type f -exec grep string {} +`?

Comment: You also want `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @wchargin: if you want the file name in the output when there's only one file I think you want `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec grep string /dev/null {} +`

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: Just pass `-H` to grep.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing - you want to grep the files in one level of subdirectory, but not recurse though all sub-sub directories?

```
grep forthis  *  */*
```

Or if you don't want the files in the current directory

```
grep forthis  */*
```

Note this won't find directories starting with a dot.

```
grep forthis  .*/*    */*
```

should do that job.

There's also `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` restriction parameters available to the `find` command too.

Comment: Wouldn't `grep forthis  */*` search files both in the current directory and one directory down?

Comment: @Hashim nope mostly - cos  `*/*` only matches things with one slash.    If you had a file named `a/b` in the current directory then `*/* would match that.

Answer (score 2):

You can think like this, for example using grep.

```
grep -l PATH ~/.[^.]*
```

So this search for string "PATH" listing name of the files below the user's home directory, only for files that start with a dot .

```
/root/.bash_history
/root/.bash_profile
grep: /root/.cache: Is a directory
grep: /root/.config: Is a directory
grep: /root/.dbus: Is a directory
```

Using grep PATH ~/.[^.]* you'll see all occurrence, including line with searching keyword.

```
/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_history:PATH=$PATH:~/bin
/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_profile:PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
/root/.bash_profile:export PATH
grep: /root/.cache: Is a directory
grep: /root/.config: Is a directory
grep: /root/.dbus: Is a directory
```

To get rid of error redirect to /dev/null for example

```
grep PATH ~/.[^.]* 2>/dev/null

/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_history:PATH=$PATH:~/bin
/root/.bash_history:echo $PATH
/root/.bash_profile:PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
/root/.bash_profile:export PATH
```

So you can apply this pattern for searching "Apache" string in files from /etc directory-looking only in files below this main directory. You see that this don't return from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
grep Apache /etc/[^.]* 2>/dev/null
/etc/passwd:apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/sbin/nologin
/etc/services:derby-repli     4851/tcp                # Apache Derby Replication
/etc/services:derby-repli     4851/udp                # Apache Derby Replication
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to properly skip directories without hiding all errors (without `-s` param on chosen answer):

```
grep --directories='skip' 'searchString' *
```