# Grep - How to suppress the "Is a directory" line?

Tags: command-line, grep

When running

```
grep 'string' *
```

I'm getting the following messages:

```
grep: some-directory: Is a directory
grep: other-directory: Is a directory
```

How to suppress those messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use grep on all files non-recursively in a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777379/how-to-use-grep-on-all-files-non-recursively-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 5):

-s, --no-messages: Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.

```
grep -s 'string' *
```

Comment: Also, redirecting error messages to /dev/null.

I.e. `grep 'string' * 2> /dev/null`

Comment: `grep -d skip 'string' *`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to suppress error messages ("`Is a directory`"):

1. grep -s 'string' *
2. grep 'string' * 2> /dev/null